# jquery custom autocomp or autosuggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, xhtml

I have several `input[type="text"]` with class `.autocomp`. Now when i search something it gives the output from mysql database through php and outputs it out in html format using jquery quite simple.

Now my question is which is the best way among these ***[you may propose your own way too]*** ?

- Make a div `#searchbox` put it in `body` and `onkeyup()` take the
  `data` from php and output it to `#searhbox` and also *position* the
  `#searchbox` below `.autocomp` using jQuery and hide it `onclick()` `.search-cont`
- `onkeyup()` append a `.searchbox` to parent of `.autocomp` **if not
  exists** and `remove()` it on click `.search-cont`
- create several `.searchbox` in parent of `.autocomp` and `show()` and
  `hide()` accordingly

Or maybe something else?  Please do suggest.

P.S.: I don't want to use a jQuery plugin.

Comment: So, you're asking about the best way to display the results from an "autocomplete" search?

Comment: Please stop editing the question back to its original state!  There was a reason I edited it.  First off, this is *not* a forum.  It's a Q&A site.  You *don't* need the "Dear xxx," or [your name at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) (your name is already appended via the blue box on the lower right).  Second, "theoretical" questions might be closed here, so to keep it open, I've made it look more like a real question that can be answered.  We like *specific* questions about *specific* problems more so than we like questions asking for suggestions.

Comment: why are you using custom autocomplete instead of jquery autocomplete plugin ?

Comment: I don't understand the problem/question you are having. You shouldn't output html from php but only the data in JSON format. Then you'll have things much easier in rendering on client side.

Comment: there are lot of reasons @Dave but perhaps u may answer this if u like to

Comment: @theHacker is always do json i didnt mentioned that here

Comment: But I understand now, thx to Dave. @HackerManiac use the jQuery Autocomplete plugin. You can fully customize it, if there is something you need different.

Comment: @theHacker  now OP has updated question (dont want to use jquery plugins),, but has not specified reasons of using custom autocomplete.

Comment: the reason is that its only limited not everything u wanna do ! @dave

Answer (score -1):

Your first approach is the efficient one among the three.

> Make a div #searchbox put it in body and onkeyup() take the data from
>   php and output it to #searhbox and also position the #searchbox below
>   .autocomp using jQuery and hide it onclick() .search-cont

However, you can make it more efficient by positioning the searchbox through css rather than jquery. Just set its display to none once it has been positioned at the right place. Before loading the results into it make it show() through jquery and once the focus shifts from the input box, just hide it again.

Comment: but what if someone removes the removes the `#searchbox` from dev ?

Comment: Can you please explain your comment more? Why would someone remove the div id name?

Comment: some ****sucker may try to play with the system!

Comment: @HackerManiac: I don't think that's really something you need to worry about.